# How to select a button using monkey runner?

Tags: monkeyrunner

I am having an application (.apk).

I'll give you one flow. When you tap the app (that is my firstactivity) screen 1 will display.

Screen 1: Demo (on registernow)
Screen 2: Register personal details (onsubmit)
etc....,

I am going to launch the app using device.startActivity('package/.demo').

On the demo page, i need to click registernow button. Is there any way to select the button by lable name?

REgards,
Chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of selecting buttons via label name. I'm new to Monkeyrunner as well but that was one of the first disadvantages I read on the web. Appearantly it is only possible to select a button via its coordinates. Maybe someone else can confirm?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a built-in way, hence a third-party library exists: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient